# Modelling of output neuron for mixed features?

Tags: neural-networks, datasets

A dataset in artificial intelligence, in general, consists of some features (say $n$). Assume that $m$ among them are output features. I want to model this function using a neural network. So, input to my neural network is $n-m$ features and output is $m$ features. My question is about the output features.

If an output feature is a continuous random variable, then its corresponding output neuron can be trained to give continuous output. Similarly, if an output feature is a discrete random variable, then its corresponding output neuron can be trained to give discrete output.

But, I never came across the features that are [mixed random variables](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_1_mixed.php). What is the nature of the output of the neuron that is intended to give the output value for a mixed random variable, which is neither discrete nor continuous in nature?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a feature that is neither continuous nor discrete? Because, right now, I don't understand what you mean by that. Moreover, it may be a good idea to explain why you're interested in this question. Which problem are you having that involves such "neither continuous nor discrete features" (whatever that means)?

Comment: Okay @nbro, will update. Thanks.

Comment: @nbro Currently, I can find the usage of mixed random variables in theory, and maybe it is difficult to find them in an application context.